# Error 500.19 when deploying Angular 11 onto IIS 10

Tags: angular, iis, iis-10, angular11

> Config error: Cannot read configuration file

I installed the URL Rewrite module (and also the extension) and installed the websocket protocol and ISAPI filters, etc. I restarted IIS and the entire server even.

I don't even have a configuration file. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if the directory has a typo in it, IIS will also complain about not being able to read the web.config.